# SSLPeerUnverifiedException with retrofit Android?

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit

I am trying to call an API with IP address from retrofit. It keeps giving me SSLPeerUnverifiedException

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname 52.36.145.54 not verified:
 certificate: sha256/UH/7MyvvhHH4nWJMR2s5umoAVweGAhU9c/9iE30gbo4=
 DN: CN=*.uat.ntitleme.net,OU=Domain Control Validated
subjectAltNames: [*.uat.ntitleme.net, uat.ntitleme.net]
```

at

How do I resolve this?